# ServiceNow UI Action calling client and server code

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I have a UI action that I created and I am attempting to use a GlideDialogForm to get and return user input to the UI action. I am new to scripting in general (and ServiceNow in particular) and can't figure out where to stick the paces of my code to make it flow. The below gives me an error. I have reviewed mark.stanger's excellent site SNGuru article http://www.servicenowguru.com/system-ui/ui-actions-system-ui/client-server-code-ui-action/.

Thank you in advance for all of your help with my issue. I thought I was done with this UI action, and then I found out it wasn't returning anything to the script include the previous admin wrote.

Below is the overview of how this should work
Overview:
  a. ui action calls form that asks for data.
  b. form returns entered data to ui action script when user hits OK
  c. ui action script then takes entered data and does things to create the new record.
     - new record would include a lookup with the correct KB
     - new record u_parent would contain the sys_id of the created from record.
     - user entered data would be populated.

I can't figure out where to put the pieces and parts to make this code complete and return "obj" to the catalogUTILS()???

```
//Client-side 'onclick' function
function createTempCred(){
    var tableName = g_form.getTableName();
    var sysID = g_form.getUniqueValue();

    //Create and open the dialog form
    var dialog = new GlideDialogForm('Create Temporary Credential', 'u_temp_credential'); //callbackFunct no longer necessary
    dialog.setSysID(-1); //Pass in sys_id to edit existing record, -1 to create new record
    dialog.addParm('sysparm_view', 'credential_view'); //Use the Credential view of the form
    dialog.addParm('sysparm_form_only', 'true'); //Remove related lists
    dialog.render();//Open the dialog window

    //Call the UI Action and skip the 'onclick' function
    gsftSubmit(null, g_form.getFormElement(), 'btnCreateCred'); //MUST call the 'Action name' set in this UI Action
    alert(obj.username);
}

//Code that runs without 'onclick'. Ensures call to server-side function with no browser errors
if(typeof window == 'undefined')
    runServer_SideCode();

//Server-side function - not a business rule
function runServer_SideCode(){
    //returning data from the temp cred form
    var obj = {};
    obj.application = current.u_application;
    obj.username = curent.u_for_user.user_name; //u_temp_credential.u_for_user => sys_user (table).user_name (userID field)
    obj.password = current.u_temp_password;

    //testing the dot walking for the username


    var utils = new CatalogUTILS();
    var uri = utils.setTempCredential(current.caller_id,obj.application,obj.username,obj.password,current.sys_id);

    current.comments = 'to access your new credentials blah blah blah https://' + gs.getProperty('instance_name') + uri;
    gs.addInfoMessage('You did it, server super-star!');
    //action.setRedirectURL(current);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using onClick in a UI Actions the script turns into a client script and will not run server-side code.

What you need to use to make the "runServer_SideCode" method to work is to use Ajax.

Docs for Reference:  https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/geneva-servicenow-platform/page/script/server_scripting/reference/r_ExamplesOfAsynchronousGlideAjax.html

```
//Move this to a Script include and call this from your UI Action using Ajax
function runServer_SideCode(){
//returning data from the temp cred form
var obj = {};
obj.application = current.u_application;
obj.username = curent.u_for_user.user_name; //u_temp_credential.u_for_user => sys_user (table).user_name (userID field)
obj.password = current.u_temp_password;

//testing the dot walking for the username


var utils = new CatalogUTILS();
var uri = utils.setTempCredential(current.caller_id,obj.application,obj.username,obj.password,current.sys_id);

current.comments = 'to access your new credentials blah blah blah https://' + gs.getProperty('instance_name') + uri;
gs.addInfoMessage('You did it, server super-star!');
//action.setRedirectURL(current);
```

Comment: This does not work from within a scoped app. I am trying to get it to work within a scoped app so I do not have the answer yet.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article at servicenowguru.com](https://servicenowguru.com/system-ui/ui-actions-system-ui/client-server-code-ui-action/), it is possible to run both client-side and server-side code in one UI Action without Ajax.

According to the article it takes advantage of the fact that **a UI Action can be configured to run scripts either at the client or the server**. In the former case the "Client" checkbox is ticked, and in the latter case it is cleared, **but in either case the UI Action is always sent to the server**.

The client-side code is defined in the function that is named in "Onclick" field. This function is called when the UI Action button/link is clicked by a user.

However, on the way to the server the entire UI Action script gets executed regardless of whether or not the "Client" checkbox is checked. What this means is that any script in your UI Action that is not enclosed in a function will be run on the server-side.

Below is a simplified version of the UI Action example shown in the article.

**UI Action field values:**

> Name: Reopen Incident
>
> Action name: reopen_incident
>
> Client: True
>
> Form button: True
>
> Onclick: reopen();
>
> Condition: current.state == 6

**UI Action Script:**

```
//Client-side 'onclick' function referenced in "Onclick" field
function reopen(){

   //This example client-side code only ensures comments are entered
   if (g_form.getValue('comments') == '') {

   //Set comments mandatory and show a new field message
   g_form.hideFieldMsg('comments');
   g_form.setMandatory('comments', true);
   g_form.showFieldMsg('comments','Comments are mandatory','error');

   return false; //Abort submission
   }

   //Below must call the 'Action name' set in "Action name" field
   gsftSubmit(null, g_form.getFormElement(), 'reopen_incident');
}

/*
Below IF-statement runs on the server because it is not encapsulated
by a function. The condition in the IF-statement ensures that it is not
called within a browser window (i.e. on client-side).
*/
if (typeof window == 'undefined')
   serverReopen();

function serverReopen(){
   //Set the 'State' to 'Active', update and reload the record
   current.state = 2;
   current.update();
   gs.addInfoMessage('Incident ' + current.number + ' reopened.');
   action.setRedirectURL(current);
}
```